# Synology DSM 7.2: how do I fix a virtual server error page for a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask, virtualhost, wsgi, synology

I am trying to run a Flask app on my Synology Diskstation running DSM 7.2:

1. I have setup a port-based virtual host with a Python Profile loaded with the Flask module and the backend pointed to the appropriate directory.
2. I created a super stripped-down Flask app

However every time I load the app page I get the error profile sent back (and I know the virtual host is sending it because I configured a specific error profile for this app).

So I looked at:
`sudo cat /volume1/@appdata/Python3.9/log/python3.9-uwsgi.log` And found the following:
`2024-03-30T08:21:39-04:00 thisDiskStation python3.9-uwsgi[4522]: --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---`

I am sure I am making a basic error.  I am a newbie to WSGI and Flask.  Do I need to create a wsgi.ini file in the app directory?

I would appreciate any guidance!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly it was bugs in my code:

The entry point wsgi.py file needed to add the directory path for the application.
I was using the incorrect flask object in @.route

I would be more than happy to share sample DSM virtual host configuration screenshots and code files with anybody who may need them and avoid 2 days of head scratching.

HUGE thanks to: https://medium.com/@rizqinur2010/deploying-python-flask-in-synology-dsm-7-without-docker-d99f1603bc87

As an bonus, the author also provides guidance on how to log to the DSM.